# Running different tasks on individual resource sets within same node

Tags: bash, loops, parallel-processing, jobs, hpc

I asked about an issue I had with this using a different approach ([Having issues running mpi4py on large HPC system. Receving startup errors and sometimes variable errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73586677/having-issues-running-mpi4py-on-large-hpc-system-receving-startup-errors-and-so)), however I'm currently attempting two other approaches. With no success. All examples below still put the same task on each of the six resource sets.

Background: I'm attempting to distribute predictions across resource sets on a node. Each resource set contains 1 gpu and 7 cpus and there are six sets per node. Once a RS task completes, it should move on to the next prediction on in a list (part00.lst through part05.lst; in theory one per RS)

First approach looks something like this (a submission bash script calls this using **jsrun -r6 -g1 -a1 -c7 -b packed:7 -d packed -l gpu-cpu**):

```
#!/bin/bash
output=/path/  ##where completed predictions will be collected

for i in {0..5}; do
  target=part0${i}.lst
  ........     ##the singularity job script to execute using $target and $output variables
done
```

The next attempt is using simultaneous jobs steps via UNIX backgrounding (which others have been able to appropriate to do similar things that I wish to do, but for different jobs and tasks). Here I created six separate bash files with each corresponding input file ($target aka part00.lst through part05.lst):

```
#!/bin/bash

## Various submission flags here

for i in {0..5}; do
  jsrun -r 6 -g 1 -a 1 -c 7 -brs -d packed -l gpu-cpu bash batch_run_0${i}.sh &
done
wait
```

I also attempted just hardcoding the six separate bash files:

```
#!/bin/bash

jsrun -r 6 -g 1 -a 1 -c 7 -brs -d packed -l gpu-cpu bash batch_run_00.sh &
jsrun -r 6 -g 1 -a 1 -c 7 -brs -d packed -l gpu-cpu bash batch_run_01.sh &
jsrun -r 6 -g 1 -a 1 -c 7 -brs -d packed -l gpu-cpu bash batch_run_02.sh &
jsrun -r 6 -g 1 -a 1 -c 7 -brs -d packed -l gpu-cpu bash batch_run_03.sh &
jsrun -r 6 -g 1 -a 1 -c 7 -brs -d packed -l gpu-cpu bash batch_run_04.sh &
jsrun -r 6 -g 1 -a 1 -c 7 -brs -d packed -l gpu-cpu bash batch_run_05.sh &
wait
```

Thanks for any help! I'm still quite new to all of this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, attempt number two using simultaneous job steps/UNIX process backgrounding was nearly correct!

It now works. An example for one node:

Submission script:

```
#!/bin/bash

## Various submission flags here

for i in {0..5}; do
  jsrun -r 6 -g 1 -a 1 -c 7 -brs -d packed -l gpu-cpu bash batch_run_0${i}.sh &
done
wait
```

It was only a matter of incorrect flags (-n 1 -r 1, not -n 1 -r 6).